# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist

although i have the dependency in pubspec.yaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RnOa.png)

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get`? Also, try to restart VSCode

Comment: How? can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter pub get` by pressing the download button. Also, try to restart VSCode.

[image: flutter pub get]

Comment: Yes, i tried but its still the same. Did you mean delete the VS and download it again?

Comment: No, just close it and open again

Comment: I tried many times , still the same error :((

Comment: Please help me , i couldn't solve it :(((